# TextTestRunner runs 2 tests (test_methods when one is called) in pyunit

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am just trying to understand the behavior of unittest's subclasses and methods. In the following code, I want to just run test_add method and not test_sub. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong since the output proves that both the methods are being executed:

```
import unittest

def add(a,b):
    x=a+b
    return x 

def sub(x,y):
    z=x-y
    return z

class addnum():
    def calladd(self, a, b):
        sum1 = add(a, b)
        return sum1
    def callsub(self,x,y):
        diff = sub(x , y)
        print "subtraction succ"
        return diff

class test(addnum, unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        pass

    def teardown(self):
        pass

    def test_add(self):
        a1=addnum()
        if a1.calladd(1, 2) ==3:
            print "add successful"
        assert addnum().calladd(1,2) == 3

    def test_sub(self):
        assert addnum().callsub(5, 3) == 2
        print "abc"

#suite = unittest.TestSuite()
#suite.addTest(test('test_add'))
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
runner.run(test(methodName='test_add'))
```

The output is as follows:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... add successful
done.

add successful
subtraction succ
abc
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
test_add (trial2.test) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Please help. I admit my knowledge is pretty limited at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not place those lines at the end of your module alone. Otherwise, every time you import the module, this test will be run. You should wrap them like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    #suite.addTest(test('test_add'))
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
    runner.run(test(methodName='test_add'))
```

In this way, your code will be run only when the .py module is called alone and not imported. Once like that seems to work just fine and only runs the requested test.

```
test_add (__main__.test) ... ok
add successful

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Always wrap it like that so it does not matter if you forget to remove your test.

Comment: Which python are you using? I know there are some differences in unittest module for 2.7 onwards. That may explain why our runs don't match in behaviour

Comment: I've checked and cannot see much difference in the way TextTestRunner is used.

Comment: It seems that Eclipse's PyDev plugin was executing the whole module once. This is why even without using if(main), the program ran the two tests. Thanks for the direction anyway. I have switched to netbeans for convenience.

Comment: Ummm... Good to know that PyDev may cause such issues. I'm glad you've found out the issue